# What is the uniform type identifier (UTI) for an SQLite file on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, uti, info-plist

I want my app to open SQLite files. What is the proper UTI (uniform type identifier, e.g. public.plain-text for plain text files) for SQLite files?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127355/associating-sqlite3-db-to-an-iphone-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no predefined UTI for SQLite databases.

Apple's list of [System-Declared Uniform Type Identifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009259-SW1) has only `public.database`, which is too generic for you.

If you are using SQLite databases as an application file format (which implies that the app cannot open *any* random SQLite database file), you have to declare your own UTI.